# ggplot2 error: there is no package called 'ellipsis'

Tags: r

I am running the following code:

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/ggplot2_3.3.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4124698 bytes (3.9 MB)
downloaded 3.9 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpS0cYmf\downloaded_packages
> library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘ellipsis’


> ggplot(data = penguins) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g))
Error in ggplot(data = penguins) : could not find function "ggplot"
```

How can I get rid of these errors? What should I do?

Comment: What happens when you run `install.packages("ellipsis")`? Everything after your first `Error:` is moot, it indicates that `ggplot2` could not load (completely or at all).

Comment: Close any other R instances on your machine including rstudio cloud etc. Try : `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`. The key is `dependencies=TRUE`

Comment: If I run `install.packages("ellipsis")` then the code runs without issues!